# El texto se mueve en dispositivos en diseño responsivo

Tags: diseño, responsive, mediaqueries, devices

Estoy creando una página web (con CSS para el estilo) y el diseño responsivo en el navegador de la ordenador funciona perfectamente y también en las herramientas de simulacion de dispositivos. El problema fue que cuando abro el sitio web en un dispositivo móvil o TV real, algunos textos se suben o bajan alguns píxels. ¿Alguien puede explicarme eso? ¿Porqué es eso? Los textos están perfectamente en el medio...

No tiene sentido, és decir, por ejemplo no tiene  sentido que un boton con padding igual en bottom como en top no este centrado. He comprobado otros de los casos contando los pixeles con photoshop y tambien lo estan.

[image: Imagen captura en ordenador en pantalla normal]Imagen captura en ordenador en pantalla normal

[image: Imagen captura en ordenador herramientas de desarrollador a una dimension de 300px de ancho]
Imagen captura en ordenador herramientas de desarrollador a una dimension de 300px de ancho

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Imagen captura en zoom en movil de 300px a 400px de ancho

Código:

```
<a href="" class="registro">Registrarse</a>
```

CSS:

```
border: 2px solid #ba9a67;
color: #ba9a67 !important;
border-radius: 4px;
background: transparent;
padding: 3px;
font-size: 14px;
margin-left: 12px;
outline: 0;
cursor: pointer;
font-family: HelveticaNeueLTStd-Md !important;
font-weight: normal;
letter-spacing: 0.3px;
```

Este botón no tiene ningún elemento que cambie su aspecto, ni en media query css ni nada.... Si veis que a veces el fondo es mas claro es porque de fondo hay un vídeo. Este es el ejemplo mas claro que no tiene ningún sentido.

Comment: @Ruben Hernandez lo hago pero es absurdo porque el código esta bien...

Comment: @Ruben Hernandez si y nada

Comment: he acabado suponiendo que era eso aunque se ve mejor mueve algun que otro pixel

Comment: @Ruben Hernandez gracias por intentar ayudar pero ya encontré la solución en otro foro XD la solución es la pila de fuentes.

Comment: Nos ayuda mucho si compartes la solución, así aprendemos todos ;)

Comment: @Ruben Hernandez hecho, pero no me deja aceptar ni votar mi propia respuesta XDD

Comment: Se puntuara por la votación de los usuarios, yo te voto ok :)

Answer (score 1):

Esto es debido al OS (sistema operativo) y no problemas del navegador. El sistema si no tiene esa determinada fuente entonces pueden pasar cosas como las que yo describia o peor. El truco es tener una buena "pila de fuentes".

Ej.: `font-family: la fuente que quieras, alguna parecida, ultima fuente como recurso genérico`

```
font-family: "Roboto","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica", Arial;
```

Dejo un articulo más detallado sobre el tema: https://www.sitepoint.com/keep-your-font-stacks-from-falling-over/